# Transforming qcows2 snapshot plus backing file into standalone image file

Tags: qemu

I have a qemu qcow2 disk snapshot `dev.img` that is based off a backing file `dev.bak`.
How can I merge both into a standalone `devplus.img`, while leaving `dev.bak` as it is?

Answer (score 18):

I got some help from the qemu mailing list:
First copy the original base file to your standalone image file:

```
cp dev.bak devplus.img
```

Then "rebase" the image file that was backed off the original file so that it uses the new file:

```
qemu-img rebase -b devplus.img dev.img
```

Then you can commit the changes in the dev file back into the new base:

```
qemu-img commit dev.img
```

Now you can use devplus.img as a standalone image file and get rid of dev.img if you wish, leaving the original dev.bak intact and not corrupting any other images that were based off it.

Answer (score 12):

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 dev.img devplus.img
```

This detects that dev.img is based off dev.bak and creates a *standalone* devplus.img.

Comment: Rebasing didn't work in my case, but this did - THANK YOU! (situation was: merging a "disk" snapshot, which was a mistake to create in the first place)

Comment: Much better way than via `commit`, keeps all input files intact (commit "wants" to change top layer at least), also can add `-c` to compress and get smaller size.

Comment: `commit` answer is when one wants to flatten only part of backing chain. I don't see this answer can do that.

Comment: @Martian2020 what does it mean "to flatten only part of backing chain"? Do you think it is relevant to original poster's question?

Comment: well, generally speaking, it could be, image could be not directly based, but via long chain of backing images. Why do you ask?

Comment: ok, now I get your point. thanks.